# Логика работы многопоточного сервера .NET

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, сервер

Доброго времени суток!
Возникла необходимость реализовать собственный класс многопоточного сервера (с# или VB .NET - пока не определился) для дальнейшего использования в своих проектах.
Здесь вроде бы и материала много в интернете, но остаются вопросы. Ответы на них я и ищу:
Схему работы я вижу такой: Создаем новый класс и запускаем в нем сервер, класс генерирует три эвента (псевдокод):

```
 - подключилсяКлиент(клиент,данные)
 - отключилсяКлиент(клиент)
 - новыеДанныеОтКлиента(клиент,данные)
```

Класс держит информацию о каждом клиенте в виде класса клиент, в котором хранятся его номер на сервере, IP и так далее.
Клиентов может быть много

Вопрос в том, как реализовать работу потоков в таком классе. К примеру при поступлении сообщения я хочу безопасно создать эвент, что бы передать в него вышеуказанные объекты (что бы со стороны родительского класса эти данные оставалось лишь использовать без лишнего геморроя связанных с потоками). И как работать с потоками сервера из родительского класса? К примеру у сервера есть метод `send(клиент,данные)`. Как реализовать? Можно в c# или лучше просто саму суть. 
Прошу прощения за неграмотность в этой сфере. До этого работал лишь с готовой библиотекой, но она меня существенно ограничивает.

Comment: На хабре есть статья про веб сервер с кодом и объяснением: https://habrahabr.ru/post/120157/ Попробуйте начать с неё, а потом задавать более конкретные вопросы.

Comment: Эту статью я читал. На вопросы мои, о которых я написал она не отвечает.

Comment: Ну тогда удачи в разработке.

Comment: "Удачи в разработке" - это когда вопросов не осталось. Не слишком ли "уместно" Вы ответили? Я задал пару вопросов. Всего лишь хочу понять как здесь поступить.

Comment: Вы написали "я придумал, как это делать, но не знаю, как сюда подключить многопоточность". Ответ: вы придумали неправильно, так не делают. Чтобы задействовать многопоточность, посмотрите на работающий многопоточный сервер, и сделайте также. Вы пишите: нет, вот у меня есть моё решение, и как делать правильно, я разбираться не хочу, придумайте за меня, как мне всё обустроить. Ну что, удачи в разработке — вполне адекватный совет в этом случае.

Comment: Вы перевернули мои вопросы с ног на голову. Меня интересовал больше всего момент безопасного вызова события в базовом классе. Мне нужно снять всю головную боль работы с потоками у базового класса. Если на каждый вопрос отвечать ссылками или указывать на известные способы поиска инфы - можно вообще не париться с объяснением. Как насчет того, что автор очередного вопроса уже искал ответ на вопрос или даже более того - читал указанный материал, но не разобрался в нем? Прошу проигнорировать мой вопрос, ибо от Вас кроме пререканий и так называемого ФИ больше ничего не удалось услышать.

Comment: Вам дан главный ответ — вы копаете не в ту сторону. Забудьте про события, используйте Task. Начните с предъявленного материала. Если не разобрались, просто повторите код, сделайте свой сервер по образу и подобию. В процессе разработки у вас появятся конкретные и корректные вопросы, на которые можно будет дать ответ. На ваш вопросы уже второй день не дают ответа, и это неспроста.